Power bi reports not rendering due to third party cookies getting blocked because of new Chrome update
Due to a recent Chrome update all the third party cookies are getting blocked which is preventing the network request to trigger responsible for fetching power bi report details which is resulting in report not getting rendered.
Please refer below screenshots for more details.
Console warning :

Issues tab details :

Cookies Warning message in network tab :

Warning message in Application tab of console :

Any help will much appreciated.
Tried allowing third party cookies from browser's setting but that didn't worked.

That's a future warning, not an active block

Though it says its a future warning but its currently preventing the reports to render. Hence, breaking our application.
Please refer to this blog post from Google about third party cookies restrictions - https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd#report-issues

That blog post doesn't say what you claim. Warnings don't prevent anything, only errors do. Besides, even a cookie error wouldn't cause the server to stop generating HTML. If you google the actual cookie name and error you'll see this is related to authentication and sessions. Worst case, you'd have to login again.

How are you actually embedding Power BI? It's your application that hosts that HTML and controls the cookies. If you search for ARRAAfinitySameSite you'll see it's used for session management in Azure Web sites and controlled through Azure settings.

This thread may be related to the real issue - controlling ARRAAfinitySameSite and its SameSite parameter. This blog post show how it can be used in Gateway configuration.
